# Failing to see the benefit of stateless components in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React, and I made the mistake of thinking Redux is essential to writing any react app. I wrote all my components to be stateless, but I'm not really seeing the benefit:

It just feels really awkward when I have nested components catering to nested objects. At every component level, I have to pass in the all the previous indexes so the child component can update the correct value. Also, I can't even use the data passed into the FlatList because it won't be Redux aware; I have to use the data from the store.

Is this how stateless components are supposed to be written or am I doing something horribly wrong?

Example:

**State structure**

```js
{
  appetizers: [...],
  desserts: [
    ...array of deserts,
    { fruits: [
      ... array of fruits,
      { name: 'apple',
       calories: 100,
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Child class**

```js
class Child extends Component {
  update() {
    const props = this.props;
    props.dispatch(actions.eat(props.food, props.dessertIndex, props.fruitIndex));
  }
  render(){
    const props = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.update()}>
        <Text>{props.desserts[props.dessertIndex].fruits[props.fruitIndex]}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ desserts: state.desserts })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Child);
```

**parent class**

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <FlatList 
        ...props
        data={this.desserts[this.props.dessertIndex].fruits}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => (<Child food={item}, dessertIndex={this.parent}, fruitIndex={index}>)} />
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ desserts: state.desserts })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Parent);
```

**grandparent class**

```js
class GrandParent extends Components {
  render() {
    return (
      { this.desserts.map((item, index) => {
        return <Child data={item} dessertIndex={index} /> 
      }) }
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ desserts: state.desserts })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GrandParent)
```

Comment: if you try to transpile them, you [will find that stateless components are much less code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=PTAEF5K6duCgSgMIHkCyAFVA5AojgCqJhxnnTwDGANgIYDODoAygC51sCmAZgK41kAewC2AByEA7LpLaguAD26SAJswBKXOlTYA6YeKky5Ab3ihQAJxkqulgBQBKUGYsXrbPpcmh7AHhUASwA3UGAAPkcAbnNQAF94BJIIClTYZJZCAEFCPAAZPBYWZLTSqHh-SR1AqVYObhouJgMJaVknF1iPLx9_INCI6MSgA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few thoughts:

First, Redux is not *essential* to building a React app.  However, there are very good reasons to use Redux with React - I talked about a few of them in a post on [why using Redux and React together is a good idea](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/redux-with-mark-erikson/).

Second, I've seen a number of people say that you "should keep absolutely all your state in Redux, and only use functional components".  **I completely disagree with that**.  Per the [Redux FAQ entry on using Redux state vs React component state](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state), it's up to *you* as a developer to decide what state lives where.  In addition, per this Dan Abramov tweet, [it's totally fine to use class components if you need state or lifecycle methods](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/802571147963310080).

Third, it looks like your current Redux state structure is storing very nested data.  You *can* do that, but it's not the recommended approach.  Instead, [you are encouraged to keep your state flattened and normalized](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-nested-data) as much as possible, which simplifies lookups like the ones you're dealing with.  See the Redux docs section on [Structuring Reducers - Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) for examples.

Fourth, the best pattern for good Redux performance and simpler props management is to have many components connected to the Redux store, especially for things like list items.  You can pass in item IDs and other values as props to the connected component, and use those values in its `mapState` function to extract only the item that one specific component instance needs.  I've got examples of this in my post [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists, Forms, and Performance](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/), and more articles on the topic in the [Redux Performance](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).

Hopefully that points you more in the right direction.  If you've got more questions, please come drop by the Reactiflux chat channels on Discord and ask!  The invite link is at https://www.reactiflux.com .